# Can't search on a list of objects for its attributes can't use linq

Tags: c#, list, object, subclass

I have to do a project that requires to search on a list of objects of a certain class.

The objects that are inserted into the list are sub classes from the class that is declared on the list. So I have this

```
List<Vehicle> veichleList = new List<Vehicle>();
```

`Vehicle` is THE class. I have the class `Car: Vehicle`, `Moto: Vehicle`, `Boat: Vehicle`.

Each of them has the attributes `brand`, `motor` and `model` all of them are string type.

The problem is that I have to be able to search and edit the object and to display it on a ListBox for the value of an attribute without using linq.

Thank you for your time !

Comment: You need to write loops and if statements.

Comment: I don't any question here...

Comment: "without using linq"  why?  Personal challenge?  Framework version?

Comment: `foreach(item in collection) if (condition met) biglist.Add(item)`

Comment: @DStanley Sounds like homework?

Comment: It's a **`vehicle`** - not a `veichle` or something like that ...

Comment: Are `Brand`, `Motor` and `Model` properties of the base class `Vehicle`? I feel like `Attribute` was not the word you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you need...

```
class  Car: Vehicle
 {
    public string Brand {get;set;}

    public Car()
     {
       Brand="BMW";
     }
 }


foreach(var vehicle in veichleList)
{
  foreach(var prop in vehicle.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
      var name = prop.Name // gives you the name of the property in that class (in the above example it will be equal with "Brand")
      var val = prop.GetValue(vehicle , null) // gives you the value of that property (in the above example it will be equal with "BMW")
    }
}
```